# Vuetify/MapBox issue on mobile devices with absolutely positioned map

Tags: css, vuetify.js, positioning, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using Vuetify (with NuxtJS) and Mapbox. I have a top navigation bar and footer. Between the top nav and the footer I have a map (mapbox gl-js) which is absolutely positioned as follows:

```
    #map {
        top: 56px;
        bottom: 22px;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

The top and bottom positioning of the map are to take into account the height of the top nav (56px) and the footer (22px). This works perfectly on desktop view, and on mobile view using e.g. google chrome device size simulator and this is how it looks:

[image]

The issue is when I view this page on an actual phone  it shows like this on load:

[image]

You can see the bottom portion of the map is below the footer and hides the +/- button. It stays below the footer until I press on the top nav bar and slide it up so as to minimize the mobile browser bars (url of the site on the top nav, and back button, home, favourites, open tabs on the bottom bar).

The map page is as follows:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div id='map'></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Layout file (default.vue)

```
<template>
    <v-app>

      <v-app-bar></v-app-bar>

      </nuxt>

      <v-footer class="footer"></v-footer>

    </v-app>
</template>
```

```
.footer {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Any ideas on the best way to fix this issue?